# NTUSER reg entries does not get reflected in Current user

Tags: windows, registry, user-profile

I need to make customization to all new users and I chose modifying registry to achieve this. When I loaded default user NTUSER.DAT file and add, all current user changes. Though I see most customization keys are imported, I have problem with few keys.

Even though they are loaded in HKEY_USERS\NTUSER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer, i dont see the same in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer.

this applies to few other keys as well.

any suggestion/help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` holds the user settings **for the currently logged in user** (and is usually abbreviated `HKCU`). This is actually just **a link** to `HKEY_USERS\<SID-FOR-CURRENT-USER>` where `<SID-FOR-CURRENT-USER>` you can find in [Win32_UserAccount class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-useraccount), e.g. as `wmic.exe useraccount get Name, SID`.
This hive is automatically loaded from file `%USERPROFILE%\ntuser.dat` on signing in, and you can see it running `dir /A %USERPROFILE%\ntuser.dat`.

The `HKCU` has nothing to do with a hive loaded to the registry from file `C:\Users\Default\NTUSER.DAT` (and named as `NTUSER` in your case). If you make changes to this *default user profiles registry*, all **new user profiles** will be equally affected.